# how to print odd and even rows into two columns in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and i want to print the result in following format.

```
insert into recipes values (1, 'Scrambled eggs');
insert into recipes values (2, 'Fondue');
insert into recipes values (3, 'Sandwich');
insert into recipes values (4, 'Tomato soup');
insert into recipes values (6, 'Liver');
```

Expected Result:

```
 **left_title | right_title**
         NULL | Scrambled eggs
       Fondue | Sandwich
  Tomato soup | NULL
        Liver | null
```

I was able to write a sql like below to get the expected result. But wondering if there are other ways to get the expected result.

```
with left_cte as (
    SELECT g,r.title,row_number() over() as id FROM 
    generate_series(0,7,2) as g  left join recipes r on g = r.page_no
    ),
    right_cte as (
    SELECT g,r.title,row_number() over() as id FROM 
    generate_series(1,7,2) as g  left join recipes r on g = r.page_no
    )
    select l.title,r.title from left_cte l join right_cte r using (id)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this in SQL at all?

Answer (score 0):

I just used a full outer join and a where clause to take the evens from a and the odds form b:

```
select a.title,b.title 
   from recipes as a 
   full outer join recipes as b 
      on a.id+1 = b.id
   where a.id%2=0 or b.id%2=1
   order by coalesce(a.id,b.id);
```

Comment: thank you jasen. This is working and can you please explain on this condition "on a.id+1 = b.id" which i find it bit hard to understand.

Comment: this is because the right column has an id 1 greater than the left column id  when both columns have values,